# Converting log time stamp Date Time offset/dst to epoch time

Tags: python, time, epoch

I am trying to convert date/time stamps that look like this:

20160131|235501[-0700/0]
20160621|225549[-0600/1]

to epoch time.  These come from a remote machine that is in a different time zones so I need a method that works only with the time stamps and not the local machine time.

I've found a similar questions, but I was not able to find a clear answer to how to properly handle offsets as a general case since the time stamps come from a different time zone than the local machine.  The python doc's don't provide enough context for me to understand how to work with time offsets.

Since this code needs to run on a small ARM system, I am limited to python 2.7.9

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's surely a more pythonic way to do this but if you can install [dateutil](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) maybe something like this works:

```
# epoch_date.py    
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
import re

raw_dts = '20160131|235501[-0700/0] 20160621|225549[-0600/1]'
dts = raw_dts.split(' ')
print '{:27s} {:5}'.format('date/time stamp', 'epoch')
for dt in dts:
    dt_fmt = re.compile(r'[^\d-]+')
    time_str = dt_fmt.sub('', dt)
    time_date = ''.join(time_str[:-1])
    date_obj = parse(time_date)
    tz = date_obj.tzinfo
    epoch_fmt = (date_obj - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1,tzinfo=tz)).total_seconds()
    print '{:28s}{:7.1f}'.format(dt, epoch_fmt)
```

will print

```
$ python epoch_date.py
date/time stamp             epoch
20160131|235501[-0700/0]    1454284501.0
20160621|225549[-0600/1]    1466549749.0
```

Ingore most that is just formatting over a list of dates into output, but the idea is using `re` to organize the text into a `datetime` object that can be parsed by `datetime`

Hope that helps!